# How could response be checked conditionally?

Tags: karate

I'm doing data driven test with Karate, and met a block issue. The REST API response body is in different structure with different status. For example, when the status is 200, the response body is JSON array. When the status is 4** and 5***, the response body either is string or blank.  I hope to check the response conditionally using the blow code. But seems it doesn't work.

```
    "* eval if (verInfo.statusCode == 200) (match each response contains any verInfo.respBody)  //verInfo.statusCode and verInfo.respBody is from the test data(DDT)
    * eval if (verInfo.statusCode != 200) match response contains verInfo.respBody"
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you cannot mix Karate script and JavaScript like this.

Second I suggest you use the [`responseStatus`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#responsestatus) built-in variable. I also suggest using proper data-driven approaches instead of over-engineering your tests with conditional logic.

So you can do this, (and there are many other ways if you go through the docs and examples):

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given url 'http://foo.bar'
  And request <req>
  When method post
  Then match responseStatus == <code>
  And match response == <body>


Examples:
    | req | code | body  |
    | 'a' | 200  | 'foo' |
    | 'b' | 400  | ''    |
```